# Get File Name And Directory by DoubleClicking in Explorer C#

Tags: c#, explorer

I have an media player program with axwindowsmediaplayer and i want to get file name and directory from explorer with doubleclicking to the file in c# windows form. Thanks for help :D

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you double-clicking this file? Do you list them in your application? Please provide more information so we can help you.

Comment: Based on what little information you've given us, it sounds like you want to use an [open file dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx), but without more information, an idea of what code you have tried already etc, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Why can`t you use a FileOpenDialog?

Comment: @DiadoI am gonna play a music file with my own media player with built in Windows Form and i have already used FileOpenDialog

Comment: @Jerodev I want to open my program with doubleclicking a song file and for that i have to get file name to add my form listbox and file path to axwindowsmediaplayer to play song

Comment: You want to read the `args` passed intot the Main function. Then try using "Open with" and select your programm. If that is working, you can set your programm as default inside the Windows settings.

Comment: @FatihUslu So is your issue something to do with how you are using the FileOpenDialog? Is it something else, such as how to create a file association programmatically? There's still not enough information to do anything other than vaguely guess at what you need help with, so you may want to read the [ask] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

in `Programm.cs`

change the signature for the `Main`method to folloging

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
```

then pass `args[0]` (if existing) to the Constructor of your `Form`

```
Application.Run(new Form1( args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : null ));
```

and change the signature of the form to accept a `string`.

```
public Form1(string path)
{
```

Now you can ckeck `path` if it is not `null` and for example call the function to play the file.

Comment: @FatihUslu what have you tried, show us you code in the Question. I started this answer, because it looked like, you don't even had a starting point.

Comment: that works thanks, i was playing the music in the form1 func , but then i tried to play the music in form1_load func and it works, thanks a lot!